# Why my HTML5 script is not working in IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have the follow html5 page which simply set`s the background for the canvas, it works in Chrome and Firefox but it`s not working in IE9. Please help me to figure out
my script: http://www.tutorialswindow.com/Jatek/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 requires you to declare an HTML5 doctype to use the canvas tag. You can do this by placing  at the top of your code.  I noticed you do not have the proper doctype present.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```